# Функция выдает "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Tags: linux, c

Программа написана на языке Си.
ОС: Linux Ubuntu .
Редактор: Sublime Text 3 .

Функция getDataFromFile() считывает масив структур и возвращает количество записей в файле. В цыкле ищет польностю все расходи и потом, после цыкла, делит их на среднее количество записей (тоесть ищет среднемесячный расход). Но при компиляции выводит либо 0.000000 либо "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".

```
void average_spends()
{
    int n = getDataFromFile();
    float mspend = 0;

    for(int i; i < n; i++)
    {
        mspend += recover[i].all;
    }
    mspend = (float)mspend / (int)n;

    printf("%f\n", mspend);

}
```

Структура объявлена следующим образом:

```
typedef struct Recover 
{
    char month[40];
    int year;
    float food;
    float rent;
    float other;
    float all;
} Recover;
```

Функция getDataFromFile() :

```
int getDataFromFile()
{
    FILE *file;
    char *file_name = "text.txt";
    file = fopen(file_name, "r");

    int is = 0; 
    while(!feof(file))
    {
        fscanf(file, "%s %d %f %f %f %f", recover[is].month, &recover[is].year, &recover[is].food, &recover[is].rent, &recover[is].other, &recover[is].all);
        is++;

    }

    return is-1;
}
```

Как решить вышеописанную проблему?

Comment: У вас в цикле for переменная `i` ничему не присваивается. Попробуйте инициализировать её нулём.

Comment: Блин. Не доглядел. Думал посерьезнее ошибка) Все работает

Comment: Оформил в качестве ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i; i < n; i++)
```

Замените на

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```